# Labview - Increasing Array Index with Array Size Limiting

Tags: arrays, labview

I'm working with a labview XY line plot that uses a random number generator for y values and the while loop count for x values. Upon reaching a threshold x value, say 1000, I'd like to be able to iterate across the past 1000 values and display only every 10th (This has the effect of de-cluttering the plot). Ideally the method for achieving this would be expandable for higher threshold values so that the plot has the following format:

Every 1,000 values, step size is 10

Every 10,000 values, step size is 100

Every 100,000, step size is 1,000

etc.

Below is the code I've been working with, and a picture of the VI. My question is, is there a better way to achieve this effect without having to delete values from the arrays as I am currently doing (inside the for loop)?

Code

[image: Code]

Virtual Instrument

[image: Virtual Instrument]

Comment: What about the intermediate data omitted in the plot? Will you ever need it, or can it be dropped?

Comment: I'd like to hold on to it in the array, but in terms of displaying, it can be dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is called "decimation" (literally here i think, as you are breaking it down by 10s). There is a function in LabVIEW for decimating arrays, more info on that can be found [here](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/decimate_1d_array/).

This seems like a simplified version of what you are trying to do using the decimate VI

[image]

There are configurable decimating VIs that can be used from the Signal Operations palette that can do the decimation with a decimation factor, see [here](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvanls/decimatecont/) or from 3rd party packages. MGI has one on one of their palettes called MGI Decimate Array with Offset. You can replace the decimate function in the code above with any of those and change the decimation factor based on the size of the array coming in.

EDIT: @JonathanVahala was asking about using configurable decimation below. See this image which shows a way to do this:

[image]

You can replace the case structure with this one to decimate this way.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful!

Comment: @JonathanVahala If it's helpful, upvote the answer.

Comment: @JonathanVahala Glad this was helpful!

Comment: As another note: I am not sure what this application is, but you should be aware that the "Build Array" function can be inefficient for building large arrays. It would be better to initialize the array to the size that you expect to need (or slightly larger) and then replace each element as you generate it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Follow up if you don't mind... I would like to apply the decimate with increasing factors as the array size increases (Array size 1000, factor of 10... Array size 10,000, factor of 100... etc.). I'm struggling with how I can apply each of the decimate functions at the appropriate threshold. I had intended to track the array size separately and reset to 0 once a decimate has been applied so that it will act again 1000 data points later. This doesn't work for anything over 1000 though as the array size will be reset before reaching higher thresholds.