# Labview Array Index Tracking

Tags: arrays, indexing, labview

Currently working with a pretty simple XY plot (Y values from a random generator, and X values from the while loop count). These are both stored in arrays and at certain X thresholds, the Y array will be decimated to certain factors (10, 100, 1000...).

However my goal with this VI is to be able to decimate in "chunks." So in other words, every 1,000-point chunk, decimate the array with a factor of 10. And every 10,000-point chunk, decimate with a factor of 100. After each of these chunks, the arrays should continue to index at +1 until they reach another "chunk" and then be decimated appropriately.

For example;

```
Index: 998, 999, 1000, 1001... Decimate Factor 10

       1998, 1999, 2000, 2001... Decimate Factor 10
       ...
       9998, 9999, 10000, 10001... Decimate Factor 100
```

(my current setup permanently changes the decimation factor once it reaches a certain X value, and from then on will only record data points in increments, of 10, 100, 1000...).

Thanks for any help! See code below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answered as an edit on the original thread this question was asked:

[Labview - Increasing Array Index with Array Size Limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383862/labview-increasing-array-index-with-array-size-limiting/56386018)

Copying info from there:

EDIT: @JonathanVahala was asking about using configurable decimation below. See this image which shows a way to do this:

[image]

Comment: Tested this and it works, but I managed to create a solution using a 2d array with each row storing a decimated version of the data array and graphing each row as necessary. Thanks for your help @Daniel Stark